# Port mapping using gateway and microservices in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, gateway

Maybe I do not understand well the mapping of the port using docker-compose and a very simple gateway. All the project is working fine except for the gateway.

My application.yml is the following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway

  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: usermanager
          uri: http://usermanager:1111
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/
        - id: catalogmanager
          uri: http://catalogmanager:2222
          predicates:
            - Path=/catalog/
        - id: paymanager
          uri: http://paymanager:3333
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment/**
```

While the docker-compose is:

```
version: '3.4'

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  DATASOURCE_USER: ${DB_USER}
  DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  DATASOURCE_PORT: ${DB_PORT}

services:
  apigateway:
    image: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  paymysqldb:
    container_name: paymysqldb
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3313:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE_PAY}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - paystorage:/var/lib/mysql


  usermysqldb:
    container_name: usermysqldb
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3311:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - userstorage:/var/lib/mysql

  catalogmysqldb:
    container_name: catalogmysqldb
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3312:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE_CATALOG}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - catalogstorage:/var/lib/mysql

  paymanager:
    container_name: paymanager
    image: arausa/payimage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MicroServices/PaymentManager/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - paymysqldb
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    restart: always
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      PM_DATASOURCE_HOST: ${DB_HOST_PAY}
      PM_DATASOURCE_NAME: ${DB_DATABASE_PAY}

  usermanager:
    container_name: usermanager
    image: arausa/userimage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MicroServices/UserManager/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - usermysqldb
    ports:
      - "1111:1111"
    restart: always
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      UM_DATASOURCE_HOST: ${DB_HOST_USER}
      UM_DATASOURCE_NAME: ${DB_DATABASE_USER}

  catalogmanager:
    container_name: catalogmanager
    image: arausa/catalogimage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MicroServices/CatalogManager/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - catalogmysqldb
    ports:
      - "2222:2222"
    restart: always
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      CM_DATASOURCE_HOST: ${DB_HOST_CATALOG}
      CM_DATASOURCE_NAME: ${DB_DATABASE_CATALOG}



#kafka usa zookeeper tiene traccia dei broker, topologia della network e info per la sincronizzazione
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper

#identifica il broker kafka
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"  #porta di default per il broker kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181  #serve a dire dove sta girando zookeeper


volumes:
  userstorage:
  catalogstorage:
  paystorage:
```

The returned error on a call like: http://localhost:8080/user/getAllUser
is the following:

````
ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [4b1c3833-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/user/getAllUsers"
apigateway_1      | 
apigateway_1      | io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: usermanager/172.24.0.9:1111
apigateway_1      |     Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
apigateway_1      | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
apigateway_1      |     *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
apigateway_1      |     *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/user/getAllUsers" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
apigateway_1      | Original Stack Trace:
apigateway_1      | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
apigateway_1      |     at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:155) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.74.Final.jar!/:4.1.74.Final]
apigateway_1      |     at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:128) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.74.Final.jar!/:4.1.74.Final]
apigateway_1      |     at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:320) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.74.Final.jar!/:4.1.74.Final]```


I'm trying to create a simple gateway that the request made on localhost/8080 route through the different microservices. Can someone explain me if something is wrong configured?
````

Comment: Completely ignoring all of the Docker setup, what port does the `usermanager` application listen on?  Use that port for connections between containers, and also as the second `ports:` number should you choose to make that service externally visible.

Comment: Can I ask You what to do in the code?